# Proper Discontinuity of $SO(2)$ action on $S^k$

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space, metric-geometry

The complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^n$ can be [represented as](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complex+projective+space) $\mathbb{C}P^n\cong S^{2n+1}/S^1$ where the elements of $(z_1,\dots,z_{2n+2})\in S^{2n+1}\subseteq \mathbb{C}^{2n+2}$ is quotiented via:
$$
\pi:(z_1,\dots,z_{2n+2})\mapsto \{e^{i\theta}\cdot (z_1,\dots,z_{2n+2}):\theta \in [0,2\pi)\}
.
$$
I've managed to show this but I can't figure if it's true that this action is *[properly discontinuous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/properly+discontinuous+action)*.  But is it even true?

In other words, is: the map $\pi_\circ \iota$ where $\iota:S^{2n+1}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2n+2}$ a covering map?

Comment: Smooth actions of Lie groups of nonzero dimension are *never* properly continuous.

Comment: So $\pi$ isn't a covering projection?

Comment: No, it is not. Covering maps always preserve dimension, while this map reduces dimension by $1$.

Comment: @Kajelad Sorry, I mean $\pi$ restricted to $S^{2n+1}$ so thechnically the map $\pi_\circ \iota$ where $\iota:S^{2n+1}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2n+2}$.

Comment: As Kajelad says, the sphere has real dimension $2n + 1$, while the projective space has real dimension $2n$.

Comment: @ArtificialHuman I assumed you were talking about the quotient map $\pi:S^{2n+1}\to\mathbb{C}P^n$. Regardless of the domain and codomain, if $G$ is an Lie group acting freely and properly on a manifold $M$, then $\dim(M/G)=\dim(M)-\dim(G)$, so if $\dim(G)>0$ as it is here, the quotient map will never be a covering map.